# BatchSize not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, api, soap

I'm trying to retrieve couple of things from MC, and following the documentation we should be able to set the BatchSize and in the response we should get the number of results same as BatchSize which was previously set.
However, even if I set the BatchSize in the request, the SOAP API always returns the default number of results (2500 if the requested resource has more results than that).

Are there any limitations with BatchSize when we try to include it in RetrieveRequest?

I've also tried using their POSTMAN SOAP collection and the BatchSize just gets ignored.

Edit with sample:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:par="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                <soapenv:Header>
                <fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">${token}</fueloauth>
                </soapenv:Header>
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <RetrieveRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
                    <RetrieveRequest>
                        <ObjectType>Send</ObjectType>
                        <Properties>CreatedDate</Properties>
                        <Properties>EmailName</Properties>
                        <Properties>SendDate</Properties>
                        <Properties>Subject</Properties>
                        <Properties>NumberSent</Properties>
                        <Properties>ID</Properties>
                        <Properties>Unsubscribes</Properties>
                        <Properties>UniqueClicks</Properties>
                        <Properties>UniqueOpens</Properties>
                        <Properties>SoftBounces</Properties>
                        <Properties>OtherBounces</Properties>
                        <Properties>HardBounces</Properties>
                        <Properties>Status</Properties>
                        <Options><BatchSize>200</BatchSize></Options>
                    </RetrieveRequest>
                    </RetrieveRequestMsg>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: can you provide a sample of the code you are using? That should help us debug your issue.

Comment: I've updated my question with SOAP envelope. Whatever I add to BatchSize it still returns 2500 items in result.

Comment: After attempting your example, I am experiencing the same issue - which is blowing my mind a little as I have used this before almost identically with absolute success.

Comment: That doesn't sound good. -.-